# Incorrect type returned in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble with my viewmodel. I have a create method, and create method that is post. In my viewmodel I am sending two classes ProjectModel and ActivityLogModel. The problem I am having is the error below. It wants the data back as ProjectViewModel, but the data is from a ProjectModel. How do I correct this so that the data is returned as the correct type.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'GlobalNaming.Models.ProjectModel', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'GlobalNaming.Models.ProjectViewModel'.

ViewModel

```
    public List<ProjectModel> Project { get; set; }
    public List<ActivityLogModel> Activity { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ProjectViewModel projectvm = new ProjectViewModel();
        ProjectModel project = new ProjectModel();

        project.ProjectOwner = UserName;
        project.Description = _description;
        project.Timing = _timing;
        project.Availability = _availability;
        project.Positioning = _positioning;
        project.Competitor = _competitor;

        projectvm.Project = project;

        return View(projectvm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ProjectModel pm, HttpPostedFileBase files)
    {
        pm.CreatedDate = dtNow;
        pm.UpdatedDateTime = dtNow;
        pm.ProjectStatus = "Initiation";
        pm.Rejected = false;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(pm);

            db.SaveChanges();

            UpdateSupportDocs(pm, files);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pm);
    }
```

Comment: {`...Create(ProjectModel ProjectModel,...`} - Don't name your variables the same as a class definition.

Comment: When does the error occur?

Comment: `return View(pm);` <-- that is not `ProjectViewModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very clear from the error message that you are sending some type from the action method and the form  is expecting a different type.

Why are you using the domain model in your ViewModel as a property ? This will make your ViewModels tightly coupled to your domain models.

You should update your viewmodel like this

```
public class ProjectVM
{
  public string ProjectName { set;get;}
  public string ProjectOwner { set;get;}
  //and other relevant properties ONLY  here
}
```

Use that to transfer and receive data from and to your view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new ProjectVM();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now make sure your View is strongly typed to the Viewmodel. not the domain model.

```
@model ProjectVM
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ProjectName)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

and your HttpPost action method will have the parameter of type ProjectVM so that MVC model binding will bind the posted form variable to that.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProjectVM viewModel)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //Create domain model object and set the property values and save
     Project proj=new Project();
     proj.Name=viewModel.ProjectName
     proj.ProjectOwner=viewModel.ProjectOwner;

     db.Projects.Add(proj);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Created");
   }
   return View(viewModel);  //returning your view model object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the wrong type in the post action. See below:

```
return View(new ProjectViewModel { Project = pm });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first metod you `return` a `ProjectViewModel` and in the secund metod you return a `ProjectModel`. So either you merge them and try to use the same, or you create different views.

In your view you have

```
@Model ProjectModel
```

Which means that this view will only accept object with the type `ProjectModel`

I saw that your ProjectViewModel has a property for the ProjectModel so you could also change the return to:

```
return View(new ProjectViewModel { Project = pm })
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, problem is input parameter `ProjectModel pm` parameter of HttpPost `Create` method.

You rendered `ProjectViewModel` in HttpGet `Create`, so that is what is posted back, not ProjectModel. So just align type you render on GET request and type you expect in input params in Post handler.

This would work:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ProjecViewtModel pvm, HttpPostedFileBase files)
    {
        // TODO:
```